# .net MVC Redirect with JWT Token

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, jwt

I have an MVC application in the .net framework. I would like a controller to redirect to an external URL (a controller inside a different project in .net core), passing along a JWT Token. Is this possible?

I currently tried using **RedirectResult** to redirect to External controller.

I don't know if it would work with a cookie because each application will be in different domains.
Can I attach this JWT token in the redirect that takes to the controller in the other application?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options:

- Use cookies. If you are redirecting to the same domain (or a subdomain, I think) this will work, but if you are redirecting across domains it will not.
- Use your controller to proxy the whole request. Instead of redirecting, your server makes the request, adding any extra headers you need for authentication. This is probably the option which is most likely to work for you, but be aware that it adds extra load to the server.
- Include the jwt in the redirect url as a query parameter. This only works if the url you are redirecting to will check the query parameters. **It also makes the jwt very insecure**, so if you have no other choice but this option, make sure you give the jwt a *very* short lifespan i.e. one minute, and restrict it to the exact operation/endpoint that you expect the user to use it for.